# Symfony 2 prefilled form with data from the database

Tags: php, database, forms, symfony

I am trying to populate form fields with data from the database in order to edit them. I already searched on google.

Here is my controller which returns empty fields

```
public function userViewAction($id,Request $request){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('BFVMailingBundle:MailingList');
    $user = $em->findById($id);

    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form',$user)
        ->add('unsubscribed','checkbox')
        ->add('name','text')
        ->add('givenName','text')
        ->add('additionalName','text',array('required'=>false))
        ->add('familyName','text',array('required'=>false))
        ->add('emailValue','text')
        ->add('language','choice',array(
            'choices'  => array('en_GB' => 'en_GB', 'es_ES' => 'es_ES', 'fr_FR' => 'fr_FR'),
            'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('commentary','textarea',array('required'=>false))
        ->add('save','submit')
        ->getForm();


    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // perform some action, such as save the object to the database
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_view',array('id'=>$id)));
        }
    }
```

and this is my template

```
<div class="cell">  
    {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'}}) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

Did I miss something?

**EDIT - READ THIS FOR THE SOLUTION**

As John Noel Implied I build an externalised form with the command

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:form BFVMailingBundle:MailingList
```

*my entity was MailingList instead of User*

the MailingListType is a form template which is generated in BFV\MailingBundle\Form. I've added the data types myself.

```
<?php
namespace BFV\MailingBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class MailingListType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $str = date("U");
    $codeValue = sha1($str);

    $builder
        ->add('secretCode','hidden',array( 'data' => $codeValue ))
        ->add('name','text')
        ->add('givenName','text')
        ->add('additionalName','text',array('required'=>false))
        ->add('familyName','text',array('required'=>false))
        ->add('emailValue','text')
        ->add('language','choice',array(
            'choices'  => array('en_GB' => 'en_GB', 'es_ES' => 'es_ES', 'fr_FR' => 'fr_FR'),
            'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('unsubscribed','checkbox')
        ->add('commentary','textarea',array('required'=>false))
        ->add('save','submit')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'BFV\MailingBundle\Entity\MailingList'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'bfv_mailingbundle_mailinglist';
}
}
```

In the reformated controller I add to add the the form generator the instance of MailingList $user[0] instead of $user. I read in many websites that usually you put $variable directly in the form builder but that generated the following error:

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class 
BFV\MailingBundle\Entity\MailingList, but is a(n) array. You can avoid 
this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a
view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of 
BFV\MailingBundle\Entity\MailingList
```

Thus in the controller:

```
    public function userViewAction($id,Request $request){
    if (!$id) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No id !!');
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('BFVMailingBundle:MailingList');
    $user = $em->findById($id);
    if (!$user){
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No user with the id selected');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new MailingListType(), $user[0]);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_view',array('id'=>$id)));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('BFVMailingBundle:Default:user_view.html.twig',array(
        'user'=>$user,
        'form'=>$form->createView()
            ));
}
```

Conclusion: I got the view form rendering with populated data from the database.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-data-class

Comment: What have you found on google?

Comment: when you do `dump($user)` do you see any record being pull against the user?

Comment: Yes I do see records retrieved from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you'll want to look into [form classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) which will then act as a view (and will also populate) the data you provide. So in your example you'd create a form class `UserType`:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('unsubscribed','checkbox')
            ->add('name','text')
            ->add('givenName','text')
            ->add('additionalName','text',array('required'=>false))
            ->add('familyName','text',array('required'=>false))
            ->add('emailValue','text')
            ->add('language','choice',array(
                'choices'  => array('en_GB' => 'en_GB', 'es_ES' => 'es_ES', 'fr_FR' => 'fr_FR'),
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('commentary','textarea',array('required'=>false))
            ->add('save','submit')
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Your\Entity\Class',
        ));
    }
}
```

Then within your controller you'd do something along the lines of:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
```

Then the rest of your controller as you have. Definitely read up on form classes though as that's the starting point for a lot of the advanced functionality of [Symfony forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html).

Comment: I tried this and it works well when you create a email user but returns this error when trying to create the form from existing data" The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class BFV\MailingBundle\Entity\MailingList, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of BFV\MailingBundle\Entity\MailingList"

Comment: Finally it worked I repladed $user with $user[0] to return the object as the error says

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what makes the difference, but did you try with:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
             ->add(...)
             ->getForm()
```

You may also check that the User you get is correctly read from the DB.

For example:

```
if (!is_object($user)) {
   $this->createNotFoundException('The user does not exist');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the data user is retrived from the database there is no problems with that. and the small try you gave provoqued an error